# Drag/Drop to arrange vertically within ScrollBox

Tags: delphi

I was asked to make some changes to a project another developer did 10+ years ago in Delphi 7. This is a proprietary bit of code, so I'll be extremely specific.

The "Container" is a TScrollBox and the panels inside are TSpkRollPanel's -- a collapsible or expandable TPanel derivative.

I hope the image below explains everything. It's really simple. I'm supposed to make the TSpkRollPanel elements drag/drop vertically ONLY so they can be arranged in the desired order. I've spent a few hours getting up to speed on Delphi (Which I haven't seen in 10+ years)

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it. I'm Delphi literate, just rusty.

[image: See Example GUI Here]

Comment: What a coincidence. I did something similar a few weeks ago: [TfrmBoxerMain.TabMouseMove](https://github.com/stijnsanders/tools/blob/master/Boxer/Boxer1.pas#L610)

Comment: Awesome thanks! Every little bit helps!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With standard `TPanel` panels the following works fine, and most probably with your panels as well. The steps are the following:

1. Select all panels
2. Set `Align` property of all panels to `AlTop`
3. Set `DragMode` property of all panels to `dmAutomatic`

Switch to event view in `Object Inspector`

4. Double click in entry field of `OnDragDrop` to create event handler
5. Double click in entry field of `OnDragOver` to create event handler

If the names of the two created event handlers include identifier for a specific panel, you may want to rename the event handlers to reflect that they are common for all panels.

6 Finally, add code to event handlers

```
procedure TForm1.PanelDragDrop(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  TPanel(Source).Top := TPanel(Sender).Top - 5;
end;


procedure TForm1.PanelDragOver(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer;
  State: TDragState; var Accept: Boolean);
begin
  Accept := True;
end;
```

The solution works so that when a panel (A) is dropped on another (B) it (A) will take that panels (B) place in the alignment order, pushing (B) and the other panels down.

Comment: Thanks! That puts me on the right path. Much appreciated! I'd like to see some "animation" during the drag... so maybe I should use onMouseMove? If so, I'd need to know the control under the control being dragged. But this helps. I can get fancy later.

Comment: @user3466851 Take a look at [this document](http://www.blong.com/conferences/borcon2001/draganddrop/4114.htm), by Brian Long, and the chapter regarding "Drag control objects".

Comment: That helps! My Delphi skills have evaporated.